# PHP how to convert date from different language

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm beginner in php, I really need help, I have a question everybody help me please, I'm making a scraping data, from other website,the website have data like `07 Ogos 2015`. when I write this in controller

```
public function UMKDATA()
{
  $data = array();
  $this->load->library('simple_html_dom');
  $this->load->model('Vtender_Data');
  // create HTML DOM
  $html = file_get_html("http://www.umk.edu.my/index.php/en/component/k2/item/180-tender-dan-sebutharga");
  // get title
  $strA = $html->find('.itemFullText tbody tr');



  $j = 0;   
  foreach($strA as $strB)
  {
    if($j >= 1)
    {
        $strB->innertext;
        $strC = str_get_html($strB->innertext);
        $masuk['Title'] = str_get_html($strB->find('td',1)->innertext)->find('span',0)->plaintext;
        if($this->Vtender_Data->check($masuk['Title']) == 0)
        {
             $masuk['source'] = $strC->find('td',0)->plaintext;
          // $masuk['Opening_Date'] = $strC->find('td',2)->plaintext;



             $masuk['Posted_Date'] = date('y-m-d', strtotime($strC->find('td',3)->innertext));
           //$masuk['Posted_Date'] = $strC->find('td',3)->plaintext;
             $masuk['Document'] = str_get_html($strC->find('td',4)->innertext)->find('a',0)->href;
             $masuk['URLNAME'] = 'UMK' ;
             $this->Vtender_Data->masuk($masuk);
        }
    }
    $j++;
  }

}
```

Date `Posted_Date`  in my db look like this `1970-01-01`, what should I do? I have to change the language or what, so that data in db correct and look like `2015-08-09`.

Comment: use date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Answer (score 1):

You have to write:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

`Y` means: A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits

`y` means: A two digit representation of a year

look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php